# Getting relation table like nested objects in Propel ORM

Tags: select, orm, find, propel, relation

I have a query:

```
UserQuery::create()
   ->leftJoinWith('User.Employee')
   ->select(array('Email','Password','Status','Employee.Email','Employee.FirstName','Employee.LastName'))
   ->find();
```

How to get Employee table as nested object, not like list of columns?

I have:

```
[
   "Email":"test@test.pl",
   "Password":"test",
   "Status":true,
   "Employee.Id":"4",
   "Employee.FirstName":"roman",
   "Employee.LastName":"stonoga"
]
```

But I have to have:

```
[
   "Email":"test@test.pl",
   "Password":"test",
   "Status":true,
   "Employee": { 
      "Id":"4",
      "FirstName":"roman",
      "LastName":"stonoga"
   }
]
```

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This is because Propel is treating your array the same way as how your objects are structured/related. i.e. Employee as sub-entity within User, and NOT as one object.

If you want one object, then maybe a view will help.

[Another view-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566863/propel-custom-sql-for-view-tables/24295355#24295355)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a foreign key for this

```
$userArray = $User->toArray()
$userArray['employee'] = $User->getEmployee()->toArray()
```