# How to have views on the Propel orm as a query class?

Tags: php, mysql, orm, propel, propel2

I have a database with two tables and one view, I use `propel init` for creating a project, now when I just have my two tables on the Propel created files and I can just get query from my tables I don't access to my view for getting the query from it!

I read some of the related issues on their Github repository about views on propel but doesn't find any way to take my view like my tables on PHP,

Anyway for now I want to know is there any way to have my view on the propel and use that class like table normal query class for getting the query from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A view is just a virtual table, so for your model based on a view, you need to define columns normally, and add `readOnly="true"` and `skipSql="true"` attributes on your table element.

The `skipSQL` tells propel not to generate a DDL SQL statement for the table, and `readOnly` tells propel suppress mutators/setter, `save()` and `delete()` methods. See [Propel Documentation](http://propelorm.org/Propel/reference/schema.html#table-element).

For a detailed explanation / example, have a look an my response on a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566863/propel-custom-sql-for-view-tables/24295355#24295355).